# Strange behavior passing scope to directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created a directive below:

**html:**

```
 <div image-upload></div>
```

**directive:**

```
angular.module('app.directives.imageTools', [
    "angularFileUpload"
])
    .directive('imageUpload', function () {
        // Directive used to display a badge.
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: "/static/html/partials/directives/imageToolsUpload.html",

            controller: function ($scope) {

                var resetScope = function () {
                    $scope.imageUpload = {};
                    $scope.imageUpload.error = false;
                    $scope.imageUpload['image_file'] = undefined;
                    $scope.$parent.imageUpload = $scope.imageUpload
                };

                $scope.onImageSelect = function ($files) {
                    resetScope();
                    $scope.imageUpload.image_file = $files[0];
                    var safe_file_types = ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg']
                    if (safe_file_types.indexOf($scope.imageUpload.image_file.type) >= 0) {
                        $scope.$parent.imageUpload = $scope.imageUpload

                    }
                    else {
                        $scope.imageUpload.error = true
                    }

                };

                // Init function.
                $scope.init = function () {
                     resetScope();
                };
                 $scope.init();
            }
        }
    });
```

This directive works fine and in my controller I access `$scope.imageUpload` as I required.

Next, I tried to pass into the directive a current image but when I do this `$scope.imageUpload` is undefined and things get weird...

**html:**

```
 <div image-upload current="project.thumbnail_small"></div>
```

This is the updated code that gives the error, note the new `current`.

```
angular.module('app.directives.imageTools', [
    "angularFileUpload"
])
    .directive('imageUpload', function () {
        // Directive used to display a badge.
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            replace: true,
             scope: {
                current: '='
            },
            templateUrl: "/static/html/partials/directives/imageToolsUpload.html",

            controller: function ($scope) {

                var resetScope = function () {
                    $scope.imageUpload = {};
                    $scope.imageUpload.error = false;
                    $scope.imageUpload['image_file'] = undefined;
                    $scope.$parent.imageUpload = $scope.imageUpload

                    if ($scope.current != undefined){
                        $scope.hasCurrentImage = true;
                    }
                    else {
                        $scope.hasCurrentImage = true;
                    }

                };

                $scope.onImageSelect = function ($files) {
                    resetScope();
                    $scope.imageUpload.image_file = $files[0];
                    var safe_file_types = ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg']
                    if (safe_file_types.indexOf($scope.imageUpload.image_file.type) >= 0) {
                        $scope.$parent.imageUpload = $scope.imageUpload


                    }
                    else {
                        $scope.imageUpload.error = true
                    }

                };

                // Init function.
                $scope.init = function () {
                     resetScope();
                };
                 $scope.init();
            }
        }
    });
```

What is going on here?

```
    scope: {
        current: '='
    },
```

Everything works again but I don't get access to the `current` value.

Maybe I'm not using `scope: {` correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your updated code you use an isolated scope by defining `scope: {current: '=' }` so the controller in the directive will only see the isolated scope and not the original scope.

you can read more about this here: http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/directives.html in the scope section

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm not fully understanding the post yet.  How do I pass in the variable without losing the whole scope?

Comment: you are welcome. the current variable will hold only string values?
if so you will pass `$attrs` to your controller and access `$attrs.current` as follows:
`controller: function($scope, $attrs){$scope.current = $attrs.current; ...} ...`